# Program working, but I'm still getting a NoMethodError 'length' nil

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

This program takes two arrays of strings and subtracts the length of the longest in a1 from the shortest in a2, and then vice-versa and returns the greater.

It works (passed 103/103 tests), but I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass 
main.rb:10:in `mxdiflg'
main.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Where's the issue? And since this isn't the first time this has happened, how do I debug a program that works?

```
def mxdiflg(a1, a2)
    if a1 == '' || a2 == ''
    -1
  end
  a1_order = a1.sort{|left, right| left.length <=> right.length}
  a2_order = a2.sort{|left, right| left.length <=> right.length}

  a_total = a1_order.reverse[0].length - a2_order[0].length
  b_total = a2_order.reverse[0].length - a1_order[0].length

  if b_total > a_total
    b_total
  else
    a_total
  end
end
```

Comment: If this method takes "two arrays of strings" then why are you checking to see if those values are equal to an empty `String`?

Comment: You're quite right, that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with fixing your program. First of all, you say you're accepting arrays of strings, yet `if a1 == '' || a2 == ''` checks whether you passed empty strings. Putting `-1`, not a `return -1` does essentially nothing.

I am assuming that the error is in this line (you have the line in stacktrace, it's `main.rb:10:in 'mxdiflg'` therefore line 10 for you):

```
a_total = a1_order.reverse[0].length - a2_order[0].length
```

As if your array is empty, your `array[0]` will be `nil` so you cannot call `.length` on it (just as the error you pasted says suggest).

As for debugging, at some point you will have to get comfortable with using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), but for now it should be enough that you check the line number and error message. In this case, it's quite clear that you're calling `.length` on a `nil`, so your `a1_order[0]` must be `nil`, so your array must be empty. You may also add simple puts messages, for example:

```
puts "a1_order: #{a1_order}"
puts "a2_order: #{a2_order}"
a_total = a1_order.reverse[0].length - a2_order[0].length
b_total = a2_order.reverse[0].length - a1_order[0].length
```

Now when running your program, you can inspect your sorted arrays and it should be quite clear that you're trying to call methods on `nil`s.

Now, having that covered, we can try to make your program a bit nicer. First of all, as I mentioned, your first check doesn't make much sense. Let's turn it into:

```
return -1 if [a1,a2].any?(&:empty)
```

which will actually return from your method with `-1` if any of arrays are empty.

Going further:

```
a1_order = a1.sort{|left, right| left.length <=> right.length}
```

can be written as:

```
a1_order.sort_by(&:length)
```

Calling

```
a1_order.reverse[0]
```

is a bit inefficient, as it will create a copy of your array with a reversed order, you may simply do `a1_order.last` instead.

If looking for maximum/minimum values, you may use [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) / [Enumerable#min_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) like so:

```
a_total = a1.max_by(&:length).length - a2.min_by(&:length).length
b_total = a2.max_by(&:length).length - a1.min_by(&:length).length
```

And getting a higher value can be achieved with [Array#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-max):

```
[a_total, b_total].max
```

Wrapping this all together, your method may look like this:

```
def mxdiflg(a1, a2)
  return -1 if [a1, a2].any?(&:empty?)

  a_total = a1.max_by(&:length).length - a2.min_by(&:length).length
  b_total = a2.max_by(&:length).length - a1.min_by(&:length).length

  [a_total, b_total].max
end
```

Comment: That's much nicer and error free, thanks for explaining the methods.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues is how you are checking for empty arrays.

```
irb(main):002:0> [] == ''
=> false
```

Will always return false even though the array is empty. empty? is one way to check for empty arrays, see below.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

    def run

    p  mxdiflg(["aa" , "b" , "c"], ["dddf", "r", "u", "ee"] )
    p  mxdiflg([], ["f", "r", "u", "ee"] )


    end


    def mxdiflg(a1, a2)

      # return whatever you want if any of the arrays is empty
      return false  if  a1.empty?  || a2.empty?

      # drop empty elements form array
      a1.reject!(&:empty?)
      a2.reject!(&:empty?)

      a1_order = a1.sort{|left, right| left.length <=> right.length}
      a2_order = a2.sort{|left, right| left.length <=> right.length}

      a_total = a1_order.reverse[0].length - a2_order[0].length
      b_total = a2_order.reverse[0].length - a1_order[0].length

      (b_total > a_total) ? b_total : a_total

    end


    run
```